# C - argument is of type struct <anonymous>

Tags: c, struct, typedef

I get the error for the two arguments of my function:

```
//incompatible type for argument of swapStruct
//expected Men100mParticipant but argument is of type struct <anonymous>
```

My code is like this:

```
int main(){
   ...

   swapStruct(phaseToBeSorted->phase_result[j-1], phaseToBeSorted->phase_result[j]); //error

   ...
}
```

phaseToBeSorted is of type Men100mPhaseDetails that is defined as:

```
typedef struct Men100mPhaseDetails{
  char* nameCurrentPhase;
  int current_phase; 
  Men100mParticipant phase_result;
} Men100mPhaseDetails * Men100mPhaseDetails;
```

While pase_result is supposed to be an array of Men100mparticipant. The typedef is given as is and I can't change it.

This is the declaration of Men100mparticipant:

```
typedef struct {
char nameOfParticipant[MAX_LEN_NAME];
double* scores[4];
} Men100mparticipant, *Men100mParticipant;
```

and this the declaration of the function swapStruct:

```
static void swapStruct(Men100mParticipant a, Men100mParticipant b);
```

I don't understand what is the problem and I'll be glad to get some help in solving the problem.

Comment: This code doesn't compile. Provide a minimal and complete example.

Comment: What is `Men100mParticipant`?

Comment: Also `phaseToBeSorted->phase_result[j-1]` and `phaseToBeSorted->phase_result` are not of the same type. And as `phaseToBeSorted->phase_result` is a `Men100mParticipant`, then `phaseToBeSorted->phase_result[j-1]` cannot be a `Men100mParticipant`.

Comment: Also^2: Is this `typdef ... } Men100mPhaseDetails * Men100mPhaseDetails;` a typo, or what's the idea behind  `... * Men100mPhaseDetails;`?

Comment: Using this: `typedef struct {
char nameOfParticipant[MAX_LEN_NAME];
double* scores[4];
} Men100mparticipant, *Men100mParticipant;`, where the case of the first letter P determines whether the type is a pointer or not, is a disaster in the making.  In general, [Is it a good idea to typedef pointers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750178/is-it-a-good-idea-to-typedef-pointers) says "No".  When there is a need (I'm not convinced this is an example of when it might be needed), make the difference clearer than the use of upper-case vs lower-case part way through the name.

Comment: You need to use `swapStruct(&phaseToBeSorted->phase_result[j-1], &phaseToBeSorted->phase_result[j]);`.  The compiler is doing its best, but the structure type names are confusing.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thank you very much, it actually work but why is a '&' needed ? I definitely agree with you and the whole exercise is about how working if pointers is horrible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use:

```
swapStruct(&phaseToBeSorted->phase_result[j-1], &phaseToBeSorted->phase_result[j]);
```

The compiler is doing its best, but the structure type names are confusing.

> It actually work but why is a '&' needed?

The type of `phaseRoBeSorted->phase_result[j-1]` is `Men100mparticipant` with two lower-case p's — so it is a structure.  The `swapStruct` function takes two arguments of type `Men100mParticipant` (with an upper-case P), so it takes two pointers.  The `&` passes the address of the array elements, of course, so that the function gets pointers, not copies of the structure.

---

This `typedef` (which appears to be given by the course instructors and can't be changed) is gruesome:

```
typedef struct { … } Men100mparticipant, *Men100mParticipant;
```

The case of the first letter P determines whether the type is a pointer or not, which is a disaster in the making. In general, [Is it a good idea to typedef pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750178/is-it-a-good-idea-to-typedef-pointers) says "No". When there is a need (I'm not convinced this is an example of when it might be needed), make the difference clearer than the use of upper-case vs lower-case part way through the name.